# How do I convert for loop to while loop in a method?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to convert a for loop method to a while loop method.

```
static boolean isPrime(int n)
   {
       for(int i = 2 ; Math.pow(i, 2) <= n ; i++)
           if(n % i == 0)
               return false;
       return true;
   }
```

I got this so far but when It prints I output different numbers. What am I missing?

```
static boolean isPrime(int n)
   {
      int i = 2;
      while (Math.pow(i, 2) <= n)
      {
         i++;
         break;
      }
      if(n % i == 0)
         return false;
      return true;
   }
```

Comment: There is a `break` in your while loop which is making it loop at most one time only.

Comment: `break;` - this is unconditionally called in the loop, so if will only loop once.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `break` in your while loop, and put `if check` inside while loop.

```
public boolean isPrime(int n)
{
    int i = 2;
    while (Math.pow(i, 2) <= n)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
            return false;
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the if statement checking for n%i == 0 inside the while, not outside